# Get Duplicate Updates Within a Time Period

Tags: mysql

I have a table called **UPDATES:**

This is the schema for this table :

Update:

```
UpdateID | UpdateTime
```

I have a table called BADUPPDATES:

```
BUpdate_ID | UpdateID | Reason
```

How can i get a list of duplicated Updates which have the same Reason and occur within 0-59 seconds(Time on the Updates table) ?

Comment: @Strawberry nuff sed ?

Comment: @Strawberry `SELECT a.UpdateID from Update a JOIN BadUpdates b ON a.UpdateID = b.UpdateID  WHERE b.IP = b.IP AND SECOND(a.Time) BETWEEN 0 AND 59;` Is this correct ? i can't be sure especially at my WHERE query.

Comment: Without seeing proper DDLs it's a little hard to help, but under what circumstances might b.IP not equal b.IP?

Comment: Sorry its a mistake, ignore the "IP" and replace with "Reason". I don't know if doing b.Reason = b.Reason is right but from what i want, i just want updates that have the same "Reason" that occured within that time interval.

Comment: OK. Under what circumstances might b.reason not equal b.reason, or 1 not equal 1, etc. ? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a list of updates with a particular difference (or less) in time, then use a join:

```
select bu1.UpdateId, bu2.UpdateId as Duplicate_UpdateID
from badupdates bu1 join
     badupdates bu2
     on bu2.Reason = bu1.Reason and
        bu2.time >= bu.time and bu2.time <= bu.time + interval 59 second and
        bu2.UpdateID <> bu.UpdateID;
```

This will return all possible pairs of duplicates.

EDIT:

Ah, now that I see where the time is, more joins are needed:

```
select bu1.UpdateId, bu2.UpdateId as Duplicate_UpdateID
from updates b1
     join
     updates b2
     on b2.time >= b1.time and b2.time <= b1.time + interval 59 second and
        b2.UpdateId <> b1.UpdateId join
     badupdates bu1
     on bu1.UpdateId = b1.UpdateId join
     badupdates bu2
     on bu2.UpdateId = b2.UpdateId and
        bu2.Reason = bu1.Reason;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort on this site by helping us get through challenges. I am a fan of your great work ! Thanks for the Query. I have a little problem. time is on the parent table called `Update` so bu.time for example won't work

Comment: Is it wise to create a view and include Time in the fictional table then run this query on ?

Comment: @Undisputed007 . . . In MySQL, views may make queries easier to read but they make them harder to optimize.